# How to import vitamio 4.0 to android studio

Tags: android, vitamio

I hear that vitamio 4.0 run better than newer version so I use this, but when I import it then get error Error:(4, 0) Project with path ':ZI' could not be found in project ':VitamioBundle-4.0'.

My step: File=>New=>Import Module and choose folder extract from vitamio4.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

`compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'`
in your Gradle built